# Putting WooCommerce Review content into product summary

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a WooCommerce product page and I need the reviews to appear in the 'summary' div.

Does anyone know a filter or function that can do this? I have searched the internet and not found a solution that relates to the reviews section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a filter for after product summary, here is a similar issue:

https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203107147-Move-WooCommerce-Product-Tabs-To-Under-Product-Summary-On-The-Right-In-Canvas

The filter is woocommerce_after_single_product_summary